# Are there any limitations on the use of Town Portal?

Tags: diablo-iii

Other than the fact that it takes ~5 seconds to go off, are there any restrictions on which areas or at what times I can create a town portal?

(Maybe I'm just thinking too old-school, but it just feels too convenient if I can do it anywhere and anytime so I feel like I must be missing something here.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only other restriction is that you cannot use it during a boss encounter. Other than that, use it as much as you want, whenever you want!

Comment: ...and that's what I was overlooking.  I forget that boss rooms are treated specially now.

Comment: Surely it's a relief from having to carry that damned Book of town portal and buying replacements for the scrolls...

Comment: @Kappei I'm not arguing THAT! :)